# Trying to add phaser-swipe file to my typescript project

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, phaser-framework

I'm pretty new to javascript and typescript and I'm having difficulty adding a library to my project.

I have a phaser.io typescript project in VS2017 and I'm trying to add this library to it:

https://github.com/flogvit/phaser-swipe

I've copied the definitions file into my folder "tsDefinitions\phaser-swipe.d.ts" and copied the js file into "build\libs\swipe.js"

I added a reference to the definition file in my project.

```
/// <reference path="phaser-swipe.d.ts" />
```

When I try to create the swipe class like in the documents I get the error "Cannot find name Swipe".

My Level01.ts:

```
export class Level01 extends Phaser.State {

    background: Phaser.Sprite;
    music: Phaser.Sound;
    player: Player;
    swipe: Swipe;
    create() {                
        this.background = this.add.sprite(0, 0, 'level01-sprites','background');
        this.player = new Player(this.game, this.world.centerX, this.world.centerX);
        this.player.anchor.setTo(0, 5);

        //Here is where the intellisense error is occurring 
        this.swipe = new Swipe(this.game);       
    }
}
```

Quick Actions adds the following to the top of the file, but it then breaks Phaser.Player and other references by giving the same "Cannot find name Player" error.

```
import Swipe from "phaser-swipe";
```

swipe.js:
https://github.com/flogvit/phaser-swipe/blob/master/swipe.js

phaser-swipe.d.ts: https://github.com/flogvit/phaser-swipe/blob/master/phaser-swipe.d.ts

Am I missing something here? How can I get the definitions file to work correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess that you should try making it a variable like

var Swipe = require(‘phaser-swipe’);

//Then in your create

this.swipe = new Swipe(this.game);

//then in the update it’ll be all just depending how you want to use it.

Always check your comas”,” and this”;” cz a simple coma can give you errors trust me I know x) hope it helps.